# Prevent the usage of some types in templates

Tags: c++, c++11

I have designed my own implementation of std::vector which I call il::vector. I would like either to:

- Specialize it for types that you can copy using `memcpy` (`int`, `double`, `std::array<double, n>`, etc..).
- Use a different class for types that you can't copy with `memcpy` such as `std::vector`. In the latter case, I want to have a compile-time error if I want to instantiate with something that can't be copied with `memcpy`, such as `il::vector<std::vector<double>>`.

Is there a way to do that ?

PS: I always get answer such as: you should use std::vector instead. The main reasons I use my own library are:

- I want to use a pointer to construct my il::vector without the data being copied
- I want to use ptrdiff_t as an array index instead of this **stupid** size_t. Using unsigned integers for arrays indexes is one of the worst idea of the STL. Even Stroustrup seems to be against it.
- I want to use my own allocators which are designed to be allocators, not this strange model of the 90s which was designed for a different purpose.

Sorry to be a little bit rude, but I am sick of: STL is god, don't even say that it does not fit your needs.

Comment: @user657267 I don't really understand your answer. Besides, I don't want to use the C++ Library.

Comment: The point is that `std::copy` will already perform a `memcpy` or equivalent on trivially copyable types, and use copy constructors otherwise. `I don't want to use the C++ Library` Have fun reinventing the wheel then.

Comment: @user657267: I am developing libraries that are often called from Fortran/C/Delphi. When I get data, it is in form of a pointer. There is no way to encapsulate a pointer in std::vector. Unless I find a way to do that, I can't use the standard library.

Comment: you are using C++ and you are still using memcpy? is there any reason? Also "I don't use the C++ library" and having tagged the question with C++ and C++11 - don't you think you are slowing yourself down unnecesarily?

Comment: @InsideLoop `std::vector<int*>` `std::vector<void*>` etc., although presumably that's not what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11, you may use traits `std::is_trivially_copyable`.

For an error case, may do something like:

```
namespace il
{

template <typename T /*, typename Allocator*/>
class vector
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "type should be trivially copyable");

    /* Your implementation */
};

}
```

To select different implementations you may use `std::conditional`

```
template <typename T /*, typename A*/>
using myvector = typename std::conditional<std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,
        il::vector<T>,
        std::vector<T>
    >::type
```

Comment: I didn't know about `std::conditional`. Looks like a very useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the type trait [is_trivially_copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) in conjunction with static assert.

```
template<typename T>
class IlVector {
  static_assert(is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,
              "Vector requires memcpy able type");
// ...  
};

int main() {
  IlVector<int> a;
  IlVector<double> b;
  IlVector<std::array<int,3> > c;
  IlVector<std::string> d;
  // your code goes here
  return 0;
}
```

This will give you an compile time error if your type cannot be copied by memcpy.